# How to addEventListener to Anonymous Node (xul:dropmarker)

Tags: firefox-addon, xul, addeventlistener, xmlnode

I have inserted to the navbar this ToolbarButton:

[image: toolbar button two part]

Copyable/Pasteable Scratchpad code in Browser context of course is:

```
var doc = document; //to put this back in sdk do const doc = require('sdk/window/utils').getMostRecentBrowserWindow().document;

var navBar = doc.getElementById('nav-bar')
var btn = doc.createElement('toolbarbutton');
btn.setAttribute('id', 'hylytit');
btn.setAttribute('type', 'menu-button');
btn.setAttribute('class', 'toolbarbutton-1');
btn.setAttribute('image', 'data:image/png;base64,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');
btn.setAttribute('orient', 'horizontal');
btn.setAttribute('label', 'Hylyt.it');
////
var toolbarbuttonPanel = doc.createElement('panel');
toolbarbuttonPanel.setAttribute('id', 'toolbarbutton-panel');
toolbarbuttonPanel.setAttribute('type', 'arrow');
var toolbarbuttonLabel = doc.createElement('label');
toolbarbuttonLabel.setAttribute('value', 'toolbarbutton panel');
toolbarbuttonPanel.appendChild(toolbarbuttonLabel);
////
////
var dropmarkerPanel = doc.createElement('panel');
dropmarkerPanel.setAttribute('id', 'dropmarker-panel');
dropmarkerPanel.setAttribute('type', 'arrow');
var dropmarkerLabel = doc.createElement('label');
dropmarkerLabel.setAttribute('value', 'dropmarker panel');
dropmarkerPanel.appendChild(dropmarkerLabel);
////

navBar.appendChild(btn);
```

Now I want to `addEventListener` to the drop marker which is to the right. It is an anonymous node which I can obtain like this:

```
var anonNodes = document.getAnonymousNodes(document.querySelector('#hylytit'));
var toolbarbutton;
var dropmarker;
[].forEach.call(anonNodes, function(node, i) {
    if (node.nodeName == 'xul:dropmarker') {
        dropmarker = node;
        node.addEventListener('mouseover',function(){
            console.log('moussssse');
        },false);
    } else if (node.nodeName == 'xul:toolbarbutton') {
        toolbarbutton = node;
    }
});
```

I can attach click event listener to the button on the left just fine with this code:

```
toolbarbutton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert('toolbarbutton');
}, false);
```

However attaching to the dropmarker does not work.

```
dropmarker.addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert('dropmarker');
  dropmarkerPanel.openPopup(dropmarker);
}, false);
```

Why doesn't this work?
Appreciated

PS: Here is the DOMInspector inspection of the toolbarbutton it is the ID `hylytit`
[image: DOMInspector of ToolbarButton]

Comment: Did you look at console for errors? For example, I don't think `alert` is available in chrome context.

Comment: No errors popped. Alert works fine if you add it to the toolbarbutton.